# User alerts with external email domains not working

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, alert, configuration, outgoing-email

I have setup SharePoint outgoing email address in a specific domain i.e. `officemail.com`. Any alert setup using the same domain email address works fine.

Any user with a different email domain does not get the alerts sent out.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure that your SharePoint server added into the Exchange relay. So that they can process outside domain address.

> In Exchange Server, If anonymous Relay settings is not enabled, then
>   you must add your WFEs in the relay list.? Make sure your ALL
>   Sharepoint WFE's IPs are added in allowed Relays or Receive connectors
>   in Exchange Server. If you use multiple domains, add all of them.

Read more: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/02/sharepoint-alerts-not-working-troubleshooting-checklist.html#ixzz4AzXfHZHu

Comment: Thanks Waqas :) Setting up the relay worked for me.. I followed the video link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gj61RzL_WFc  and it worked :D